# How can I make WordPress tinyMCE Editor look like Dreamweaver code highlighting in HTML view?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wordpress

Anybody know of a plugin or something that makes tinyMCE WordPress editor in HTML mode highlight the XHTML code for better editing?

Comment: I believe you are looking for [Code Magic](http://codemagic.sutulustus.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Geishify does syntax highlighting for posts, but I don't think it runs on the dashboards...